# C# ASP.NET: How do I Turn Text into HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

How would i show the output as HTML. I have tried HTML Decode and it still didn't work.

```
@section Grid {
    @Server.HtmlDecode(lister.gen(new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Grid.xml")).ReadToEnd()))
}
```

Edit: I am taking XML from `output.InnerXml` (A XMLDocument) and trying to put it into a HTML Document as HTML (As in `<a>` is a link and `<img>` is a picture and not Text)

Comment: What's your input/output data look like?

Comment: With HtmlEncode
&lt;div class=&quot;row&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;col-md-5&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;~/Game/clicker&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;thumbnail&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

Comment: With HtmlDecode
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><a href="~/Game/clicker"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="~Media/Thumbnails/clicker.png" /></div><p>Demotivating Clicker</p></a></div><div class="col-md-5"><a href="~/Game/2048"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="~Media/Thumbnails/2048.png" /></div><p>2048</p></a></div><div class="col-md-5"><a href="~/Game/clicker"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="~Media/Thumbnails/....png" /></div><p>...</p></a></div><div class="col-md-5"><a href="~/Game/..."><div class="thumbnail"><img src="~Media/Thumbnails/..png" /></div><p>Tetris</p></a></div></div>

Comment: I'm not sure what you want then. that looks like it formatted your string into html... What's your desired output?

Comment: To show it as HTML from a XmlDocument in a web browser. (`<a>` is a [link](http://example.com) , `<img>` is a picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the HTML in an HTML page, you need to use HTML encode, not decode. This will put the proper tags in to turn < and > (and other HTML elements.

ADDED due to comment:
If showing XML AS HTML is the goal, then you will end up extracting the XML, from the DOM and putting it into the format you desire. You can bind XML to a table if you are simply trying to get it into a grid. If you need sorting, etc, LINQ to XML works nicely.

ADDED - second edit
Your XML appears to be XHTML, so you can simply throw it into the stream at the correct location. I would create a server control and then Response.Write the XML from the server control. You will want the decoded version based on what you posted. I was assuming you wanted to show the XML in the page, which was incorrect.

There is one minor bit of an issue with the XML, as it contains paragraph and div tags inside of an anchor tag. Not illegal, but not necessary in this case.

Comment: All Server.HtmlEncode did was put &gt and &lt around everything

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Display on the page as HTML or make XML into HTML?

Comment: To show it as HTML from a XmlDocument in a web browser. (`<a>` is a [link](http://example.com) , `<img>` is a picture

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to add `@Html.Raw` along with `HtmlDecode` for it to display correctly

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(lister.gen(new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Grid.xml")).ReadToEnd())))
```